# Best solution for implementing a site-version for people with poor sight

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my mind the simplest solution is to apply some css class to body tag that will reset all css styles to their defaults and keep site mode (normal or "for people with poor sight") in cookie.

But the bad thing in that solution - too much css code in this ".class-for-people-with-poor-sight".

Comment: If you're changing your site so much for people with a visual-impairment, it sounds like the original design needs some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off certain stylesheets (dynamically) using "disabled" property of `<link/>` tag.

Comment: awesome Ivan!

great solution if i have style.css

Comment: but...IF i have style.css :D